# Read 60 potentiometers and 30 switches

Tags: switches, analog, potentiometer, input

I'm pretty new to hardware stuff.
I have a basic idea to build a hardware controller for some proprietary software. I would need to read about 60 analog faders/potentiometers and 30 buttons. Also I need to drive about 40 LEds.
I have Arduino or Raspberry Pi at hand. Up to 60ms delay from mechanical movement to registered value would be ok.
I found some digital potentiometer accessible via I2C but at a hefty price (14$ per piece - I'd need about 60 of them)

Comment: Can you MUX them?

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: What exactly is your question? Switches put on shift registers to read serially, pots use ADCs, probably with analogue muxes in front of them.

Comment: fyi: Regarding last sentence about digital potentiometers. When you say "*digital potentiometer*" most people will get an image of an output device (digitally controller potentiometer).

Comment: Nick, thanks. Terminology is sometimes hard at the beginning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look for multi-channel ADCs to read your pots, chips with 16 or 32 channels are not unheard of. Or use analog muxes as Colin suggested, [here](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9056)'s a DIY friendly solution if you're planning to solder by hand.

For buttons and LEDs, you can use multiplexing or shift registers, as described e.g. [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/41995/how-do-i-control-several-hundred-individual-leds-with-arduinos).

Comment: Thanks Dmitry! That is exactly the stuff, I was looking for. It's always hard to create a clear question without knowing the exact terminology, but that lead me in the right direction.

Comment: @m_c Good luck with your project!